# Checking Against Multiple Entries in a Table - ASP.NET Core 3.1 and EFCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out the logic when checking against existing fields in a table with a single variable.  Here is my entity class:

```
public class Metadata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string MachineId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say for example the user has 3 entries in the table and we check the current machine name with the machine names in the table.  If the current machine name does not match the machine names in the table, I want to save a new entry in the table.

At the moment, my code jumps to the `else` and `returns` out of the method if the first machine name entry in the table is the same as the current machine name, which is not good as it might not be the case for the 2nd or 3rd entry.  Also if the current machine name matches the 2nd entry, it will be ignored and saved since the first entry did not match.

Here is my method:

```
private void ValidateMetadata(string userId)
{
    // get list of entities if they exist based upon the userId
    var metaList = _metadata.where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();

    if(metaList != null)
    {
        foreach (var m in metaList)
        {
            // check each machine name with current machine name
            if (m.MachineName != GetMachineName())
            {
                // create new entry
                var metadata = new { MachineName = GetMachineName(), MachineId = GetMachineId(), UserId = userId };

                // save to db
                _metadata.Save(metadata);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // create new entry if there are none in the table
        var metadata = new { MachineName = GetMachineName(), MachineId = GetMachineId(), UserId = userId };

        // save to db
        _metadata.Save(metadata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Any

```
var hasHit = _metadata.Any(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

Example

```
var test = new List<string> {"one", "two"};
var result = test.Any(x => x.Equals("one"));
```

`result` will have the value `true`

Comment: Thanks, will your first example return a `bool` or a list of `Metadata` entities?

Comment: It will return a bool. If _metadata can be null, use  var hasHit = _metadata?.Any(x => x.UserId == userId) == true;

Comment: Can I have an `&&` in the `Any()`

Comment: Yes, no problem